# I have a Macbook Pro 2012 I received this error when I ran Disk Utility Disk Utility: Invalid Disk Label @ cksum mismatch

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, mac-pro

I have a Macbook Pro 2013 OS 10.10.5. Its beach balling really bad. I ran Mbam scan and no malware was found I ran Disk Utility and it gave me the Disk Utility: Invalid Disk Label @ cksum mismatch. I also ran time machine

Comment: that was running general check or permissions check?

Comment: I ran a General check

Comment: Try checking your disk permissions with Disk Utility, i think it can work for you.